# React Native Listing Shared Files Google Drive with

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api

I'm not sure if this is possible -- but I want users of my RN app to be able to open files in their Google Drive account that are specifically shared with them, but I'm running into a permissions issue.

Google Drive has a less-restrictive `auth/drive.file` scope which gives the app access to files that are created or **opened** by the app which seems like the way to go.

However, the only way the user can view, download, or update the shared file in Google Drive is if I use the most restrictive `/auth/drive` scope.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth

Do you know of a way in RN to let the user open a shared file from Google Drive which would, I think, place the file under the `auth/drive.file` scope?

All suggestions welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: If I am understanding this right, you are looking for some kind of loop-hole within RN that allows you to bypass the Google API security scopes?

Comment: No, not trying to circumvent anything.  I was just curious if someone knew of another way of going about it that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you clarify what you mean by `I want users of my RN app to be able to open files in their Google Drive account that are specifically shared with them, but I'm running into a permissions issue.` - shared by who? By a certain account? Are the users in a domain or anything like that? Maybe some context would be helpful to be able to suggest a workaround, as it sounds like you'll just have to make do with the `auth.drive` scope

Comment: Let's say User A creates a text file using my app and uploads it to their Google Drive account.  The app can see the new file in GD because the permission /auth/drive.file allows the app to see that file.  No problem.  But then User A decides to share that text file with User B through the standard GD way of sharing by entering User B's e-mail address.  User B then opens my app, logs into their own GD account through the app expecting to see the file, but the app can't see it because the permission /auth/drive.file won't recognize a file not specifically created by the app on User B's phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Drive Scopes

In your situation, the `auth.drive.file` scope will not work for the workflow exactly as you have described, you would just need to make sure that the user has a chance to explicitly grant permission to the new file. See: [Handle "Open with"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open)

This is not specific to React Native or any other framework or library, this is something that is totally the domain of Google APIs.

#### How a app accesses your file

- User A creates file with the app, User A is the owner, the app has access to the file via User A's account.
- User A shared file with User B. Unless User B specifically allows the App access to that file via their account, then it won't have access.

The key concept here is that the app is accessing the files *via* a user account. Its like the app is being permitted to act *as-if* they were the user themselves. Its not about whether the app has access to it in another account, its about the app acting as-if they were the user with certain files.

This could be seen as a limitation of the Drive scopes. Though I am unsure of exactly how a new scope along these lines, might be implemented. It seems that scope of:

"if the app has access to that file, then it doesn't matter which account the app is running from, it should have access to it"

Seems like it could lend itself to security vulnerabilities.

#### A New Drive Scope

There is an active feature request for a Drive scope that will allow folders to be shared with an app. So then if someone adds a file to a shared folder, the app would have access.

> #### [Drive Restrict access to folder when authorizing applications](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760598)

I'm not sure how exactly you are implementing your app, so not sure if this would help you, but if you'd like to see that, be sure to go and 'star' the issue to let Google know that you want it.

Alternatively, if you have an idea for a new scope that might be useful, file a feature request with either of these templates:

- [Identity & Security](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187167&template=1162792)
- [Drive](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106)

#### Reference

- [Handle "Open with"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open)
- [About Auth](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth)